# rspec test fails code in rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, capybara

In my application_controller.rb, i have a line of code as follows:

```
def index
 CaseStatus.order(:application_source).pluck(:application_source).uniq!
end
```

In my rspec code, i have a line of code that visits the index path of application_controller as follows

```
visit applications_path
```

When i run the code directly, it works perfectly but when it visits application_controller.rb via rspec, i get an error which says

```
NoMethodError:
  undefined method `compact' for nil:NilClass
```

Not sure while i get this error via rspec and capybara but if i run the code as

```
def index
 CaseStatus.order(:application_source).pluck(:application_source)
end
```

It executes perfectly with no errors. Kinda confused what the `uniq!` breaks in the code that suddenly the result becomes nil.

i get this error

```
 Failure/Error: @application_channels = CaseStatus.order(:application_source).pluck(:application_source).uniq!.compact if CaseStatus.order(:application_source).present?

 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `compact' for nil:NilClass
 # ./app/controllers/loan_applications_controller.rb:53:in `index'
```

Comment: An error message usually includes the file name and line number in which the exception was raised. Can you please post the whole error message including the stack trace?

Comment: Did you create a CaseStatus with an empty application_source?

Comment: @PeterdeRidder no, CaseStatus has 2 records and both have application_source values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think `uniq!` is the method you would like to use in this case, see:

> Returns nil if no changes are made (that is, no duplicates are found).
>   https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-uniq-21

So it works like this:

```
2.3.1 :008 > a = [1,2,3,3,nil].uniq!
 => [1, 2, 3, nil]
2.3.1 :009 > a = [1,2,3,nil].uniq!
 => nil
2.3.1 :010 >
```

on the other hand `uniq` works like:

```
2.3.1 :010 > a = [1,2,3,3,nil].uniq
 => [1, 2, 3, nil]
2.3.1 :011 > a = [1,2,3,nil].uniq
 => [1, 2, 3, nil]
```

and on the output of `uniq` it is safe to run `compact` to remove `nil` values.